# Rails Format Date in Drop Down List in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, tags

I could you some assistance formatting a date field in a drop-down list in a for in a view.  My dates are showing with a time-stamp and I'd like them to show as "mm/dd/yyyy".

In my model I have a method selecting a date field from the table:

```
def self.get_event_dates
  event_dates = UgradRsvp.find_by_sql("select distinct event_date from admissions.ugrad_rsvps where event_date is not null order by event_date desc")
end
```

We use Oracle as our db, so I also tried using to_char(event_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') as event_date, but the dates in my drop-down still show with a time-stamp.

My view is a search form.  Users will select a date and then see a report of all students signed up for an event on that event_date:

```
<%= select_tag "event_date", options_from_collection_for_select(UgradRsvp.get_event_dates, "event_date", "event_date") %>
```

There are about eight dates in my table ugrad_rsvps.  They are showing as, i.e: "2013-04-18 00:00:00 -0400"  I'd like to have them show as "04/18/2013".   I've tried using strftime("%m/%d/%Y"), but I just get errors on the line in my view for the drop-down (above).

Any ideas?  Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your model add the following method

```
  def event_date_formatted
    event_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
  end
```

Then you can simply use like so:

```
<%= select_tag "event_date", options_from_collection_for_select(UgradRsvp.get_event_dates, 'event_date', :event_date_formatted) %>
```

Comment: Awesome, Luis.  Thank you.  I should have realized that on my own.  Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help you John!

Comment: This is a great answer, yet I could not find anything in the Docs for `options_for_select` about passing a method (`event_date_formatted`) as such. Can I just pass any method?

Comment: @Anh the example above is for [options_from_collection_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select). If you check the source you will see that it calls the private method [value_for_collection](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/value_for_collection) with the method passed as the parameter `value`, then it just invokes the method you've passed.

Answer (score 0):

I not try yet, but you can try to add method to Model like

```
class UgradRsvp < ActiveRecord::Base
    def event_date_text
        event_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    end
end
```

and then call event_date_text as txt_method

```
<%= select_tag "event_date", options_from_collection_for_select(UgradRsvp.get_event_dates, "event_date", "event_date_text") %>
```